# Sum of array ,two same methods different result

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have two arrays ,i wan sum of elements,but in one method i just to results have list of elements in array.

Wrong array:

```
 int[] names = {1, 24, 4, 50, 4, 1};

    int suma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {

        suma += names[i];

        System.out.println("suma" + suma);

    }
```

i have results :suma 1,suma 24...

but this is rigth:

```
int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        sum += numbers[i];
    }
    System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
```

I'm confused.

Comment: because once you print the sum in the loop, while you are still calculating the sum, and once you are doing it right, you create the sum first and print it afterwards...

Comment: It makes a difference if you print each time through the loop, or once at the end.

Comment: Your output is wrong it should be suma 1, suma 25  (1 + 24), suma 29 ( 1+24+4) in the first case after the last } suma and sum should be equal

Comment: Thanks,now i understand!

Comment: You probably do not understand how for works.  The code inside the loop executes each time, until the control variable meets the criteria for loop to end. So in your first case, the loop executes 10 times, printing suma each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  suma += names[i];
  System.out.println("suma" + suma);
}
```

there are two statements inside the scope of `for {...}`

1. `suma += names[i];`
2. `System.out.println("suma" + suma);`

Everytime the `for` loop runs it has two statements to execute. This is the reason why in the first case you're output is:

```
suma1
suma25
suma29
suma79
suma83
suma84
```

Because the `System.out.println("suma" + suma);` is executing `names.length` number of times.

In the second case however:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  sum += numbers[i];
}
```

The loop has only one statement to execute `names.length` number of times. And the output is printed outside the loop that's why your output is:

```
The sum is: 55
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case the print in inside the loop, so suma will be printed once per element in the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    suma += names[i];
    // inside the loop scope
    System.out.println("suma" + suma);
} // end of loop scope
```

In second one it's not inside loop scope, so, sum will be only printed when loops finish

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    sum += numbers[i];
}  // end of loop scope
// outside the loop scope
System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
```

Comment: Thanks,now i understand!